# Open Parent list if page is its child page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep the related list expandable if page belongs to the parent list.

Let us say i am on `Vision` page then `About` list should be open by default, only this list.

https://jsfiddle.net/9nh6tkdd/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expList").find("ol").hide();

  $("#expList > li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("ol").slideToggle();
  });

  $('#expList a[href^="/' + window.location.href + '"]').closest('li').css('display', 'block');
});
```

I tried few combination with 
`$('#expList a[href^="/' + window.location.href + '"]').closest('li').css('display', 'block');` but did nt work

Page link will be similar to

- page.aspx?p=1
- page.aspx?p=2
- page.aspx?p=3
- page.aspx?p=5 .....

Comment: I think `$('#expList a[href^="/' + window.location.href + '"]')` will be always `false` i.e. cos your `a` `href` always starts with `#` and `location.href` returns `url` without `domain name` and also you need to target its `ol` not `li`

Answer (score 0):

As per new updates, you have to use `window.location.pathname`, which returns the path of the url without protocol and domain name. Now you can use `window.location.pathname` to get the path and show the `ol` instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'page.aspx?p=5'; // change it to -> window.location.pathname;
  $("#expList").find("ol").hide();

  $("#expList > li").click(function() {
    $(this).find("ol").slideToggle();
  });

  $('#expList a[href^="' + url + '"]').closest('ol').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
.page-left-bar {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
ol {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.handbook-page ol {
  color: #687074;
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  color: #687074;
}
ol li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
ol li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #687074;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click on Contact</h1>
<div class="page-left-bar">
  <ol id='expList'>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news1">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#home">Sub menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#news1">Sub menu long name</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About </a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#home">Mission</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page.aspx?p=5">Vision</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Page URL will be similar to  `page.aspx?p=1`, `page.aspx?p=2`, `page.aspx?p=3`, ` page.aspx?p=5`

Comment: use `window.location.pathname` to get the current path out of url.

Comment: Your current issue is you are doing it incorrectly, that is something like `http://domain.com/page.aspx?p=5` which is an out put of `window.location.href` but you need to get `/page.aspx?p=5` which is output of `window.location.pathname`.